# Is it possible to customize gcloud app deploy?

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I'd like to perform some preliminary checks before running the actual deployment to AppEngine. It would be nice to put some Python find in the repository, so that gcloud would behave similarly for everyone. Does gclould provide some means for this kind of customization? Can't find this in the official docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no hooks in `gcloud app deploy`. But you could pretty easily write a small Python script to wrap the call to gcloud using e.g. the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module and have all of your users deploy via that script.

Comment: Pity... hooks would have been handy. We have CI and don't need to wrap gcloud to perform checks there, but with users used to gcloud it would be easier to force them to perform checks if they don't have to switch to another tool.

Comment: @Fedor what do you use for CI? we use app engine as well, and I am wondering the best way to do CI/CD. My thoughts are: 1. pre-push hooks to run tests and then 2. push to deploy on master branch.  
I know that if we were using docker images we could run test as part of a cloud build step, but we are on google app engine standard environment.

Comment: @BrainPermafrost that's actually a very old question from me and I think my idea was to do some check and limit the possibility of making broken versions messing shared Datastore when developers deploy their changes in dev environment (it was AppEngine standard as well). At that time we were on Travis CI for CI/CD and it worked fine with ready-made AppEngine plugin. Currently we are on GitLab CI/CD, also deploying some parts to AppEngine standard. Nowadays GCP also offers Cloud Build, however IMO building complex and flexible CI/CD pipelines with this solution is not easy.

Comment: @Fedor got it, thank you.  I see that GitLab can deploy code to AppEngine, but can it emulate the AppEngine environment to build/run tests before deploying. Or ...do we have to specify that environment.

Comment: @BrainPermafrost in GitLab CI/CD you can specify any Docker image for execution of your code, so you can create your custom image with everything you need to emulate the AppEngine environment to build/run tests before deploying. However my experience shows that simulated AppEngine environment is too far away from the real, so I'd deploy, run tests on real environment and if they pass, switch version. I think this approach is also recommended by Google.